# Functional determinant

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I have a question on functional determinant. Specifically, I have a question on one of the computation in gauge theory lecture note by David Tong (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) page 347 first equation.

To simplify the functional determinant 
$$
det(1-i(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)^{-1}(\sigma+i\pi \gamma^5) )~~~~(1)
$$
Where $\sigma$ and $\pi$ are some scalar fields.
One can sandwich the expression in the determinant with $\gamma^5$ becasue $det(\gamma^5)=-1$. 
$$
det(1+i(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)^{-1}\gamma^5 (\sigma+i \pi \gamma^5)\gamma^5)= det(1+i(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)^{-1} (\sigma+i \pi \gamma^5)) ~~~~(2)
$$
equations (1) and (2) are equal so we can multply them and squre root them 
$$
det^{1/2}(1+\bigg[(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)^{-1} (\sigma+i \pi \gamma^5)\bigg]\bigg[(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)^{-1} (\sigma+i \pi \gamma^5)\bigg])
$$
Two square brackets are matrix multiplied. Expanding the secound term (noting that $\gamma^5$ and $\gamma^\mu$ anti-commute) one finds
$$
det^{1/2}(1+\partial^{-1}_\mu \sigma\partial^{-1\mu} \sigma+\partial^{-1}_\mu \pi\partial^{-1\mu} \pi )
$$
I'm not sure how this then becomes 
$$
det^{1/2}(1+\partial_\mu \sigma\partial^{\mu} \sigma+\partial_\mu \pi\partial^{\mu} \pi )
$$
in David Tongs note?